# Quota issue in YouTube Data API V3

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, quota

When we created 3 or more live streams in less than a minute, we got the message below and the YouTube Data API was unavailable for a day.

**"User requests exceeded the rate limit."**

I know the above message is a quota problem, but I don't know how to increase the quota.

We use the following YouTube Data API to create and terminate broadcasts.

```
youtube.api.v3.V3DataLiveStreamService.List
youtube.api.v3.V3DataLiveBroadcastService.Insert
youtube.api.v3.V3DataLiveBroadcastService.Bind
youtube.api.v3.V3DataLiveBroadcastService.Transition

Total number of queries: 4 queries, Total costs: 1701 costs
```

It is known as quota per query in 'YouTube Data API v3 > Quota' in GCP Console, and as cost per API in 'YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator'.

How do I apply for a quota?

Answer (score 0):

According to [YouTube Data API Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota) about quota:

> Note: If you reach the quota limit, you can request additional quota by completing the [Quota extension request form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form) for YouTube API Services.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer does not pertain to the OP's issue. That issue is not about insufficient daily quota, but about ***User requests exceeded the rate limit***; this means the OP issued *too many API endpoint calls in a short amount of time.* That API error is normally handled by retrying the offended API call using an exponential back-off algorithm.

Comment: The ending question "How do I apply for a quota?" misleads me indeed.